# Set timeout, run function then refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to refresh the page after the set time out, so ideally after the image has downloaded in browser i would like the page to refresh.

everything i tried like:

```
then((canvas) => {
              canvasToImg(canvas, imageToPdf, imageLoadError);
        }).then("refresh")
```

just rfreshes the broswer before the timeout and before the document is downloaded.

```
setTimeout(
      function() 
      {
        html2canvas(c,
          {
            useCORS: true,
 ($(".SPPageChrome") as any).ploading({
      action: 'show'
    });


 setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
    html2canvas(c,
      {
        useCORS: true,
      }
      ).
      then((canvas) => {
          canvasToImg(canvas, imageToPdf, imageLoadError);
    });
    ($(".SPPageChrome") as any).ploading({
      action: 'hide'
    }
    );
  }, 2000);
```

Appreciate your help .

thanks

Comment: What does `canvasToImage` look like?

Comment: setTimeout is not a good way to ensure that another function has finished running.

Comment: add `window.location.reload()` atlast of `setTimeout()`

Answer (score 0):

Timer callback functions run **after** the current instructions on the call stack are complete. The callback functions sit in the Event Queue and wait to be invoked by the JavaScript runtime.

Here's an example. Note that "Job Complete" will print to the console before the timer's callback message does. The callback will run AFTER the main thread is idle.

```js
console.log("About to set up the timer....");

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("Timer callback says 'Hello'");
}, 0);

console.log("Job Complete");
```

If you want the page to refresh at the end of the timer function, place that code at the end of the timer callback function, not *after* the timer function.

```js
console.log("About to set up the timer....");

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("Timer callback says 'Hello'");
  console.log("Job Complete");  // <-- Now, this will run at the end
}, 0);
```

And, more specifically, if you want to wait until an image is loaded to do something, just set up a `load` event handler for the image.